# No Robots robots.txt Location

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, web, robots.txt

A bit confused with robots.txt.

Say I wanted to block robots on a site on a Linux based Apache server in location:

```
var/www/mySite
```

I would place robots.txt in that directory (alongside index.php) containing this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

right?

Does that stop robots indexing the whole server or just the site in var/www/mySite? For example would the site in var/www/myOtherSite also have robots blocked? Because I just want to do it for the one site.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Robots (well-behaved robots, that is -- honouring `robots.txt` is entirely voluntary) will use the `robots.txt` found in the root of your domain. If `mySite` is served off `mysite.com` and `myOtherSite` is served off `myothersite.com`, then your `robots.txt` would only be served on `mysite.com` and this works as intended.

To test, just head to `http://myothersite.com/robots.txt` and verify that you get a 404.